# Como eliminar error de CORS?

Tags: php, angular, rest, http, cors

Estoy haciendo una ApiRest con Angular de cliente y PHP en el servidor con Apache de XAMPP. Pero me marca este error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Podrian descirme si hace falta algo? Si se configura el CORS desde apache? O alguna ayuda.
(La ip que aparece es la del servidor).

Tengo este en el codigo del server PHP: (segun para permitir CORS)

```
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:  *");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
```

Y este es mi request de angular:

```
login(email: string, password: string): Observable<any>{
    const data = {'email': email, 'password': password};
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    return this.http.post<any>("http://192.168.10.202:8080/login.php?login=1", data, { headers });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *request*  no debe contener la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Esta cabecera es exclusiva del servidor, ya que con ella te está comunicando qué clientes pueden realizar peticiones.

La petición es la que debe informar sobre el *origin* enviando dicha información en la cabecera:

- `origin: XXX`

Sin embargo, esta cabecera debería dejarla ya configurada el navegador directamente, por lo que normalmente no será necesario que te preocupes por ella.

Si la petición hace un preflight (petición más ligera que verifica que la petición va a ser aceptada), en tal caso puede contener cabeceras como

- `Access-Control-Request-Method`
- `Access-Control-Request-Headers`

Con estas cabeceras se informa al servidor sobre el tipo de petición que se quiere realizar y las cabeceras que se pretenden enviar y entonces el servidor te dirá si esa petición será aceptada o rechazada.

Todo apunta que el error se esté produciendo por lo que te he comentado al principio, la petición está enviando una cabecera que no debería enviar y eso hace que el protocolo CORS falle.

Lo que te dice el servidor es que en la lista proporcionada por el servidor mediante la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` no se encuentra la cabecera `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` que estás enviando en la petición.

Borra esa cabecera y el mensaje de error, a malas, cambiará (y a buenas pues ya te funcionará)